# Why index.jsp in my spring mvc project is not accessing css,fonts,images when adding web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am making a spring mvc project everything is working fine but when I am adding external template in my project  then index. jsp is not accessing template css,images,fonts etc. Can any one please help me. Below I have given required fie and some screenshot.
[images contains my project directory][1]

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts5Jf.png`

```
**web.xml:-**
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

```
**spring-servlet.xml:-**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.control"></context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="vr"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/test/**" location="/test/" />
    
</beans>
```

Comment: Do not post code as images; post it as code. Additionally, you need to examine the HTML output in your browser's View Source tab, then debug why you can't load those links (or if the links are incorrect).

Comment: web.xml:-                                               <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>


 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using obsolete project setup instead of creating a Spring Boot ready-to-go application with https://start.spring.io?

Comment: Yes i am beginner doing in eclipse IDE so that can learn

Comment: What you're learning is obsolete. I develop Spring applications professionally and haven't used this in 7 years. I recommend against spending time on it unless you are trying to fix a specific old project.